# mybatis select query is not returning result when one of the select parameters is null

Tags: java, mybatis

I need some help on Mybatis/Java.

I have the following select in my mapper:

```
 <select id="findTxnByBusinessKey" parameterType="map" resultType="data.Transaction">SELECT 
     t.id, *MANY OTHER FIELDS NOT SHOWN HERE* FROM txns t 
     where source=#{source} and userid=#{userid} and transactiontype=#{transactiontype} and ordernumber=#{ordernumber} and utrn=#{utrn}
 </select>
```

The following is my Java code to retrieve a transaction:

```
HashMap keys = new HashMap();
keys.put("userid", userid);
keys.put("source", source);
keys.put("ordernumber", ordernumber);
keys.put("transactiontype", transactiontype);

keys.put("utrn", null); <--- *****SEE THIS LINE********
//keys.put("utrn", "1234"); <--- WORKS FINE

Transaction t = session.selectOne("findTxnByBusinessKey", keys);
return t;
```

I know that there is a row in the db where the value for the urtn column is null. I fire the same query on the db with "utrn is null" clause and it returns the row. But the above code is not returning that row. Values for other parameters are correct. The code works fine when I pass in a valid value for utrn field.

Any idea how to make mybatis generate UTRN is null when the utrn parameter is null?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's the case because your SQL statement will not be correct if there is no value set. You need to adjust your statements with an if-clause and test the parameter. So what you're doing here is creating a dynamic-SQL-statement.

You need to change the statement like:

```
<select id="findTxnByBusinessKey"
     resultType="data.Transaction">
  SELECT t.id, .... FROM txns t 
  WHERE source=#{source}
  <if test="userid != null">
     AND userid=#{userid}
  </if>
  <if test="userid == null">
     AND userid IS NULL
  </if>
  ...
</select>
```

Please make sure that a required parameter is names first because `"... where and userid=..."` would be a incorrect sql syntax in case the 1st is null and ignored.

If you got more conditions you can use a `when` in mybatis which can have many conditions and 1 default one for any other case.

Comment: But that is not what I want. 
I want : where a='a' and b='b' and c is null
Which, I think (imns), is not the same as : where a='a' and b='b'

Comment: So add a 2nd if - 1st for a value is set and in case it's null use another one. I will adjust the answer.

Comment: @Priyshrm did the updated answer fixed your needs? Would be nice if you could mark it as answered so this thread is done.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a solution where any field value could be null and the resulting query would have "is null" for that field. But it seems that is not possible with mybatis. So, although this answer was helpful but was not the solution I was hoping for. Not sure what I should do in this case about this thread.